# NicEdit interfering with JQuery $ alias

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, wysiwyg, nicedit

I am implementing the **NicEdit** editor with our own rich textbox ASP.NET control, which is just  composite control that includes a **TextArea** and registers the **NicEdit** scripts on document ready.
The rich textbox control (and all our pages/controls) are also using JQuery.

The problem is that for some reason a piece of the NicEdit code's nulls out the "$" JQuery alias. 
The following line of code executes when the control is loading:

```
onDomLoaded: function (A) {
        debugger;
        this.domLoad.push(A);
        if (document.addEventListener) {
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", bkLib.domLoaded, null)
        }
        else {
            if (bkLib.isMSIE) {
                document.write("<style>.nicEdit-main p { margin: 0; }</style><script id=__ie_onload defer "+((location.protocol=="https:")?"src='javascript:void(0)'":"src=//0")+"><\/script>");
                $BK("__ie_onload").onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
                        bkLib.domLoaded()
                    }
                }
            }
        } window.onload = bkLib.domLoaded
    }
```

The specific line of code I am talking about is:

```
document.write("<style>.nicEdit-main p { margin: 0; }</style><script id=__ie_onload defer "+((location.protocol=="https:")?"src='javascript:void(0)'":"src=//0")+"><\/script>");
```

Before this executes, the $ alias points to JQuery, after the execution of that line, it is undefined. 
I cannot seem to figure out what this line is suppose to do and why does it mess with the $ JQuery alias.

Could anyone suggest what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the **onDomLoaded** function does not work good, so I used JQuery $(document).ready()

Before:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { new nicEditor().panelInstance('area1'); });
});
```

After:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    new nicEditor().panelInstance('id');
});
```